# Pygame: update in the while loop not succesful

Tags: python, pygame

A helicopter is shot at. If he is hit, he falls. At the same time, a parachute releases from the helicopter. If the parachute is shot at and also hit by a bullet, the image of the parachute should be replaced with another image.
The jump with the parachute is done by the function `absprung`. The parachute is created with the `Fallschirm` class. The shelling is queried via collide.
It doesn't work, the picture is not changed.

```py
def absprung(self):    #Auslöser Fallschirm
    fallschirm = Fallschirm(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
    alle_sprites.add(fallschirm)
    fallschirme.add(fallschirm)

class Fallschirm(pygame.sprite.Sprite):       
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)   
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Bilder/fallschirm.png").convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(100,150))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.beschuss = False

    def update(self):      
        if self.beschuss == True:
            self.image = pygame.image.load("Bilder/fadenkreuz.png").convert_alpha()
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(100,150))      
        self.rect.y  +=2
        if self.rect.y > hoehe:
            self.kill()  


hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(fallschirme,bullets,False,True)      
for hit in hits:        
     fallschirme.beschuss = True
```

Comment: Are you sure that you call `pygame.display.update()` or pygame.display.flip()` every frame?

Comment: yes, when the helicopter ist damaged by a bullet

Comment: but  fallschirme.beschuss = True that will not accept in the updat function . when i insert there  print (self.beschuss) i get False as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beschuss` is an attribute of a single `Falschirm` object, but not an attribute of `fallschirme`. [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) returns a dictionary of objects that were hit. You must set the attribute to these objects.

```py
hits = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(fallschirme, bullets,False,True)      
for fallschirm in hits:    
    fallschirm.beschuss = True
```